# Huawei - Cannot upload watch face with the latest version Health app

Tags: watch, huawei-mobile-services, healthkit

I cannot upload my custom watch face with the latest version Health app.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot you upload, watch face with the latest version Health app,

There could be following reasons:

1. You must install the **beta version of the Huawei Health app**; otherwise, you cannot add watch faces for testing.
2. If the beta version fails to be installed, uninstall the official Huawei Health app from your phone, and then **reinstall the beta version**.
3. You must sign in to the app using a HUAWEI ID that has passed **designer certification**; otherwise, you cannot add watch faces for testing.
4. For details about designer certification, please refer to [Registration & Certification](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/content/settlement-guidance-0000001056348857).

For details , please check below guide
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/content/gtwatch-specification-0000001077917528#section1978213113313